# Pipe pid of process to file

Tags: linux, unix, pipe, stdout, stderr

I have a long running process which does nothing that I call from a shell:

```
while true; do true; sleep 10; done & $1
```

This displays the PID to the console. I'd like to read this PID into a file but I can't work out how.
I've tried doing:

```
while true; do true; sleep 10; done & $1 > /path/to/file
```

but when I look at the file, it's empty.

Does anyone know what I should do instead?

Answer (score 1):

I've actually found out how to do this using $! instead of $1. It might not be the best way but it seems to work.

```
while true; do true; sleep 10; done & echo $! > /path/to/file
```

Any other suggestions?